# Nslookup does not resolve IP addresses using the secondary DNS

Tags: windows-7, dns, ubuntu-18.04, nslookup

I have two Ubuntu 18.04 DNS servers and a Windows 7 client in a virtual environment.

I have set the Ubuntu servers for clients' DNS.

The first one is offline and the second is online.

When i try to resolve an IP adress using nslookup, the client always uses the first offline server to do it and it does not pass the queries to the secondary server.

What could be the problem?

The client can access the Internet normally through the secondary DNS server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [nslookup command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/nslookup)  will use the default DNS server. From Microsoft's documentation:

> If you omit the second argument, nslookup uses the default DNS name server.

That'll be the first one listed under such tools as `ipconfig /all`.

If you want to tell it to use your second DNS server, you can pass that as an additional argument. Assuming your second DNS server is 192.168.1.2, that would look like this:

`nslookup www.example.com 192.168.1.2`

Comment: Hi Doug, thank you for your reply. The thing i am actually trying to do for a demonstration is to show that if the primary DNS server is down for a specific reason, then the client asks the secondary server. So iam looking somehow to query a domain and the output will be that the client queries first the primary and then the secondary. Is it possible somehow to do this with nslookup? Thanks in advance.

Comment: nslookup is just going to do what you tell it to do. It won't do any automatic failover. Take a look at the answers to this question -- https://serverfault.com/q/84291/450038 -- for more info about how the DNS Client service does it. But I don't see an easy way to demonstrate that. Packet capture would show it, but that might not be appropriate, depending on your target audience.